# Running a Command Prompt from a Java program in Windows

Tags: java, windows, runtime.exec

I currently have the following batch script I want to run from my Java program:

> "C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java.exe"
>   -classpath "D:..."
>   Main >
>   "...\result.out"

Now, I've done a simple

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

where `command` is that string I have shown above. The problem is that it is simply calling `java.exe` with the shown arguments, instead of calling the console with the given arguments. The difference is subtle, for if it is calling directly `java.exe` it will ignore the redirect of the output stream!

Is there a easy way to do this? I've tried prefixing `command` with "cmd " but that didn't seem to help.

I'd like to stay away from having to read the output stream and then having to manually save this to a file.

Thanks

Comment: You can use ProcessBuilder to achieve this task. Or instead of writing whole command in s single line break it and execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the issue,

```
cmd /c "command"
```

is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("acpi -b");
```

Now you can use proc.getInputStream() and proc.getOutputStream() like any normal input and output streams.

You can then write the contents to your output file.

This is the method I mostly use.